# Best record toward Selberg's eigenvalue conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures, maass-forms

What's the best record toward Selberg's eigenvalue conjecture:
a Maass form on $\Gamma_0(N)$ has eigenvalue greater than or equal to 1/4?

Comment: See http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/254b-notes-3-quasirandom-groups-expansion-and-selbergs-316-theorem/#comment-117537 for some comments by Lior Silberman on numerical verification of the conjecture by Booker and Strombergsson (and also mentioning the Kim-Sarnak result in quid's answer).

Comment: Greater than or equal to!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

\[\frac{1}{4} - \left(\frac{7}{64}\right)^2 = \frac{975}{4096} \approx 0.238037\ldots\]
as far as I know. Established in an appendix by Kim and Sarnak to Kim's "[Functoriality for the exterior square of $GL_{4}$ and the symmetric fourth of $GL_{2}$](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1937203)", Journal of the American Math. Society, 16 (2003).

The above is "over the rationals" (which was/is my reading of the question), in comments work on the problem for general number fields got mentioned by [Kim and Shaidi, Cuspidality of symmetric powers with applications. Duke Math. J. 112 (2002)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1890650)  and the more recent work of [Blomer and Brumley, On the Ramanujan conjecture over number fields. Annals of Math. 174 (2011)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.0559) which among others establishes the above for general number fields.

For generalizations in a different direction let me also mention [Bourgain, Gamburd, Sarnak,  Generalization of Selberg's 3/16 Theorem and Affine Sieve, Acta Math. 207 (2011)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.5021) establishing 'a generalization of Selberg's theorem for infinite index "congruence" subgroups of SL(2,Z).'

Comment: And it might worth mentioning related work of Kim-Shaidi over arbitrary number field.

Comment: It is perhaps useful to note that the Kim-Sarnak result is over $\mathbb{Q}$. The same result over an arbitrary number field was established by Blomer-Brumley (Annals of Math. 174 (2011), 581-605).

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the additions! I edited in links to the two additional papers, and an additional one on a different way to generalize the problem.