# Special rational numbers that appear as answers to natural questions

Tags: big-list, gm.general-mathematics

### **Motivation:**

Many interesting **irrational** numbers (or numbers believed to be irrational) appear as answers to natural questions in mathematics. Famous examples are $e$, $\pi$, $\log 2$, $\zeta(3)$ etc. Many more such numbers are described for example in the wonderful book "Mathematical Constants" by Steven R. Finch.

### **The question:**

I am interested in theorems where a "special" **rational** number makes a surprising appearance as an answer to a natural question. By a special rational number I mean one with a large denominator (and preferably also a large numerator, to rule out numbers which are simply the reciprocals of large integers, but I'll consider exceptions to this rule). **Please provide examples.**

For illustration, here are a couple of nice examples I'm aware of:

1. The average geodesic distance between two random points of the Sierpinski gasket of unit side lengths is equal to $\frac{466}{885}$. This is also equivalent to a natural discrete math fact about the analysis of algorithms, namely that the average number of moves in the Tower of Hanoi game with $n$ disks connecting a randomly chosen initial state to a randomly chosen terminal state with a shortest number of moves, is asymptotically equal to $\frac{466}{885}\times 2^n$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) and [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01217750) for more information.
2. The answer to the title question of the recent paper ""[The density of primes dividing a term in the Somos-5 sequence](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05896)" by Davis, Kotsonis and Rouse is $\frac{5087}{10752}$.

### **Rules:**

1) I won't try to define how large the denominator and numerator need to be to for the rational number to qualify as "special". A good answer will maximize the ratio of the number's information theoretic content to the information theoretic content of the statement of the question it answers. (E.g., a number like 34/57 may qualify if the question it answers is simple enough.) Really simple fractions like $3/4$, $22/7$ obviously do not qualify.

2) The question the number answers needs to be natural. Again, it's impossible to define what this means, but avoid answers in the style of "what is the rational number with smallest denominator solving the Diophantine equation [some arbitrary-sounding, unmotivated equation]".

**Edit:** a lot of great answers so far, thanks everyone. To clarify my question a bit, while all the answers posted so far represent very beautiful mathematics and some (like Richard Stanley's and Max Alekseyev's answers) are truly astonishing, my favorite type of answers involve questions that are conceptual in nature (e.g., longest increasing subsequences, tower of Hanoi, Markov spectrum, critical exponents in percolation) rather than purely computational (e.g., compute some integral or infinite series) and to which the answer is an **exotic** rational number. (Note that someone edited my original question changing "exotic" to "special"; that is fine, but "exotic" does a better job of signaling that numbers like 1/4 and 2 are not really what I had in mind. That is, 2 is indeed quite a special number, but I doubt anyone would consider it exotic.)

Comment: If one is allowed to cheat and use quadratic irrationalities, then there is Freiman's constant: the last gap in the Markov spectrum, namely, 
 $\frac{2221564096 + 283748\sqrt{462}}{491993569}$.

Comment: Richard, that is indeed a beautiful example and very much in the spirit of what I had in mind.

Comment: There are two kinds of "famous" rational constants. First kind is when it is clear a priori that it is rational (like Bernoulli numbers). Second kind where this comes as a suprise. Like the examples in my answer.

Comment: I don't want to type it in, but there's the [simplest rational right triangle with area 157](http://www.quora.com/Number-Theory/What-is-the-simplest-right-triangle-of-area-157-with-rational-sides?), which Koblitz tells me was computed by Zagier.

Comment: $\frac{1}{12}$ seems to make a lot of unusual appearances. It’s negative is the sum of natural numbers. It appears in coefficients of some index theorems and many other places. There might be a hitchhiker style joke you can make replacing $42$ with $\frac{1}{12}$

Answer (score 107):

We have 
$$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}dx}  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}\frac{{\sin \left( {{x/3}} \right)}}{{{x/3}}}dx}  = \ldots = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}\cdots\frac{{\sin \left( {{x/{13}}} \right)}}{{{x/{13}}}}dx}  = \frac{\pi }{2}$$

But 
$$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}\cdots\frac{{\sin \left( {{x/{15}}} \right)}}{{{x/{15}}}}dx}  = \frac{{467807924713440738696537864469}}{{935615849440640907310521750000}} \cdot \pi$$

See http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1011497229317

Comment: I thought of this too but couldn't find the reference.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [that answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11517/computer-algebra-errors/11607#11607).

Answer (score 67):

Gobel's sequence is defined by the recurrence relation:
$$\begin{cases} a_0=a_1=1,\\
a_{n+1} = \frac{a_0^2 + a_1^2 +\dots + a_n^2}{n} & \text{for}\ n\geq 1.
\end{cases}$$
It turns out that $a_k$ for all $k\leq 43$ are integer, but $a_{44}$ and on are not. Namely, 
$$a_{44} = \frac{m}{43},$$
where $m$ is a huge integer not divisible by 43.

See http://oeis.org/A003504

Comment: Is there any explanation of this phenomenon?

Comment: How "huge" is $m$?

Comment: @BlueRaja about 400 billion digits according to the asymptotic estimate given in the OEIS entry (I originally figured it grew as 2^n, but it actually grows as k^(2^n) where k is slightly larger than 1).

Comment: I too am tickled by this. Why should it have remained an integer until so far before suddenly exploding?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Another recurrent formula: $a_{n+1} = a_n\cdot (a_n+n-1) / n$ may justify why $a_n$ remains integer for quite a while. It shows that $a_n$ accumulates most of the factors of the previous terms and some others. The "$/n$" cancellations happen to be minor and hit the existing factors up until $n=43$.

Comment: But if we replace $a_n+n-1$ to something like $a_n+n+1$ or $a_n+2n-1$, or add additional multiple $a_n$ in the recurrent formula for $a_{n+1}$, does similar thing happen?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: For some other coefficients, it does. E.g., $a_{n+1} = a_n(a_n+n+5)/n$ with $a_2 = 2$ remains integer for up to $a_{59}$.

Comment: See also the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282152/simple-recurrence-that-fails-to-be-integer-for-the-first-time-at-the-44th-term which links to this page of problems by Zagier http://turnbull.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/Zagier/Problems.html (day 5, problem 3).

Answer (score 44):

Perhaps rational numbers appearing in geometric probability qualify, e.g. Sylvester's four point problem:

What is the probability that four randomly chosen points (independently with uniform probability measure) in a planar region give a convex quadrilateral? 
In my opinion this is a "natural" question.

For a square the probability is $\frac{25}{36}$, for a hexagon it's $\frac{683}{972}$.

(Source: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersFour-PointProblem.html)

**EDIT** (Sept,15; another example for a “special” rational number appearing as answer of a “natural” geometric probability question):

I was mentioning this MO question and my answer today to Prof Henze (KIT) and he pointed me to the fact that the expectation value of the (unsigned) area of a triangle  the vertices of which are randomly chosen in the unit square (independently with uniform probability measure) is $\frac{11}{144}$.

(Sources:

- Henze, N. "Random Triangles in Convex Regions." J. Appl. Prob. 20, 111-125, 1983 http://www.jstor.org/stable/3213725
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareTrianglePicking.html

)

Comment: For a closely related example,  suppose we constructing a triangle by drawing 3 points uniformly at random from a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then the probability that this triangle is acute, (i.e. its largest angle is less than $\pi$) is exactly $33/70$.

Comment: @GabeK A very satisfying fraction since the factors 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 appear exactly one.

Answer (score 39):

Another example from probability theory: in critical bond percolation on the square lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$, one can define a certain family of "connectivity events," which encode information about certain points being connected to certain other points, and whose probabilities turn out to be
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(1\leftrightarrow 2) &= \frac{3}{8}, \\[5pt]
\mathbb{P}(1\leftrightarrow 2, 3\leftrightarrow 4) &= \frac{97}{512}, \\[5pt]
\mathbb{P}(1\leftrightarrow 2, 4\leftrightarrow 5) &= \frac{135}{1024}, \\[5pt]
\mathbb{P}(1\leftrightarrow 4, 2\leftrightarrow 3) &= \frac{59}{1024}, \\[5pt]
\mathbb{P}(1\leftrightarrow 2, 3\leftrightarrow 4, 5\leftrightarrow6) &= \frac{214093}{2^{21}}, \\[5pt]
\mathbb{P}(1\leftrightarrow 2, 3\leftrightarrow 6, 4\leftrightarrow5) &= \frac{69693}{2^{21}}, \ldots.
\end{align*}
There is no known simple explanation for why these probabilities are rational (let alone dyadic rational) numbers. Only the top three of these identities have been proved, using extremely complicated methods relating to the combinatorics of **alternating sign matrices**, **totally symmetric self complementary plane partitions**, and something called the **quantum Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov equation**. The remaining identities are conjectural, but the evidence that they are correct is very strong. [This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6341) reduces the proof of these conjectures to the purely algebraic problem of proving a certain family of conjectural constant term identities.

Answer (score 29):

Many percolation critical exponents are mysterious rationals, prescribed by physicists and in rare cases proved mathematically.

Example. Given $p\in (1/2,1)$, open each hexagon in the honeycomb lattice with probability $p$. Then probability that given hexagon lies in an infinite cluster behaves as $(p-1/2)^{5/36+o(1)}$ when $p$ goes to $1/2$. Why $5/36$?

This is taken from the paper "Critical exponents for two-dimensional percolation" by Stanislav Smirnov and Wendelin Werner.

Comment: I don't understand the terms (and, of course, have not read the paper) but could it just be $1/6(1-1/6)$?

Comment: It definitely equals $1/6(1-1/6)$, but is it so typical for the exponent?

Comment: As for the terms, cluster is just a connected component of open hexagons.

Comment: Wouldn't one expect $\frac{1}{6}$ to show up with connectedness in a hexagonal grid?

Comment: @user21820, the same constant $5/36$ is believed to still be the correct one for percolation on other lattices (square, triangular etc.), when the question is modified appropriately ($1/2$ should be replaced with the critical percolation threshold). So the $1/6$ is unrelated to the hexagonal strcture of the lattice. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_critical_exponents) is a page with more details and additional interesting critical exponents such as $43/18$, $187/91$, ...

Comment: @DanRomik: Ah very interesting thanks!

Comment: It is also equal to $\frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{3^2}$ which seems more related to 2D lattices.

Answer (score 23):

I wasn't thinking of mentioning this, but some of the other answers reminded me of the elegant formulas
\begin{align}
\pi^{-6} \sum_{n,m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n m(n+m))^2} &= \frac{1}{2835},
\\
\pi^{-12} \sum_{n,m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n m(n+m))^4} &= \frac{19}{273648375},
\end{align}
due essentially to Mordell (1958).

While I requested rational numbers that arise as answers to conceptual questions and these seem more of the "purely computational" variety, these formulas actually arise in connection with some deeper mathematics (the so-called Witten zeta function of $sl(3,\mathbb{C})$; volumes of moduli spaces of vector bundles of curves), some of which came up recently in connection with my own work (see section 1.2 of [my recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03776) and for additional background section 7 of [this paper](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/scanned/ValuesofZetaFunsAndApplications/fulltext.pdf) by Zagier). Anyway, they are pretty identities so I thought I'd mention it even if it's not completely in the spirit of my question.

Comment: What's the Mordell reference?  Did he do it by integrating cubes of Bernoulli polynomials $B_2$ and $B_4$?

Comment: Yes, and the same technique will work with the Bernoulli polynomial $B_{2k}$ to show that $\sum_{n,m\ge 1} (n m (n+m))^{-2k}$ is a rational multiple of $\pi^{6k}$. The reference is: L. J. Mordell, On the evaluation of some multiple series. J. London Math. Soc. 33 (1958), 368--371.

Comment: Thank you!  I rediscovered this trick of integrating $B_{2k}(x)^3$ around 1980, and never knew a source, though it was clearly unlikely that I was the first to notice it.

Comment: Great! This problem has an interesting history, and the fact I mentioned about $\sum_{n,m} (nm(n+m))^{-2k}$ was rediscovered several times. There are also better formulas for the rational coefficient of $\pi^{6k}$ than the one you get by integrating $B_{2k}(x)^3$. See the other references I mentioned.

Answer (score 21):

A somewhat silly example, which is a "fun" (i.e. hard) multivariable calculus exercise: Take a sphere of unit radius, then remove two cylinders of radius 1/2 that are tangent to each other along the $z$-axis (and so also tangent to the sphere on the boundary). What is the volume of the remaining sphere-with-holes?

Punchline: it's $\frac{16}{9}$!

Comment: Nice exercise, just verified it. It's $8$ times the volume in the first orthant bounded by $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$ and $x^2 + (y-1/2)^2 \ge 1/4.$ In cylindrical, these become $r^2+z^2 \le 1$ and $r \ge \sin \theta,$ leading to a simple triple integral.

Answer (score 18):

An *adventitious quadrangle* is a (convex) quadrilateral with the property that if its two diagonals are drawn in, all angles formed are rational multiples of $\pi$.  A classification of all such quadrilaterals was published by Bol, whose method was essentially correct but whose list contained some errors.  A correct classification was published by [Poonen and Rubinstein](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ngon.pdf).  It turns out that there are 65 "sporadic" solutions.  The rational numbers arising in these sporadic solutions could be considered exotic, although the largest denominator that arises is "only" 210.  One such sporadic adventitious quadrilateral has interior angles (in cyclic order) $139\pi/210$, $5\pi/14$, $6\pi/7$, and $13\pi/105$.

Note that adventitious angles have shown up in the popular press occasionally, e.g., the Washington Post in 1995 and in a United Airlines magazine in 2004.  It's typically phrased as an innocent-looking "find the angle in the diagram" problem that looks easy but is actually very difficult, at least if trigonometry is not allowed.

Comment: Fantastic! These are just the sort of exotic numbers and results I was hoping to learn about.

Comment: In my paper, Rational products of sines of rational angles, Aeq. Math. 45 (1993) 70-82, I found all the solutions of $$\sin\pi x\sin\pi y\sin\pi z\sin\pi w=r$$ in rational $x,y,z,w,r$. These included $$\sin\pi/42\sin5\pi/14\sin8\pi/21\sin10\pi/21=1/16$$ and $$\sin\pi/39\sin9\pi/26\sin14\pi/39\sin11\pi/26=1/16$$

Comment: Gerry, that's awesome. Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Done (didn't notice your suggestion at the time).

Answer (score 16):

Rational number 1/4 occurs as a universal constant in several problems of Analysis.
The most famous is the "Koebe 1/4 Theorem". Let $f(z)=z+\ldots$ be an injective holomorphic function in the unit disk. Then the image contains a disk $|z|\geq c$ where $c$ is an absolute constant. This was discovered by Koebe, and for some time the optimal value was even called the "Koebe constant". The optimal (greatest for which this is true) constant was later proved to be $1/4$.

An apparently unrelated subject. The family $\phi_n(x)=e^{inx}$ is a Riesz basis in the space $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. For a sequence of real numbers $\Lambda=\lambda_n$, consider the family $e^{i\lambda_nx}$. If $|\lambda_n-n|<c$, and $c$ is sufficiently small, this is
also a Riesz basis. (This is due to Golovin, I guess). This was known for some time before M. Kadets proved that the optimal
(greatest) $c$ for which this is true is $1/4$. This remarkable result is called the
"Kadets 1/4 theorem".

A priori reasons why these two numbers should be rational are not clear. Both numbers are defined as solutions of sophisticated extremal problems, so it was totally unclear why they should be rational until these extremal problems were solved.

EDIT. There are also conjectured extremal problems with a rational answer. One is mentioned in the comment of Noam Elkies below. Another is a conjecture of Carleson and Jones, where (surprise!) the extremal constant is also 1/4, or 3/4, depending on notation, but I was never able to understand the reasons why they made such a conjecture:
MR1162188. They say it is suggested by numerical computation but the details of this computation were never published.

Comment: There's also Selberg's $1/4$ conjecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg%27s_1/4_conjecture , but $1/4$ is surely too ordinary a rational number to qualify.  (Selberg proved $3/16$, and the current bound seems to be $975/4096$ http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145637 which would be sufficiently exotic except that it's a bound that's not expected to be the actual minimum.)

Comment: Yes, sure. I just forgot it:-( You may enter this as another answer or to edit my answer.

Comment: I won't answer with a rational number as simple as $1/4$; if you want to edit your answer go ahead.

Answer (score 16):

$$\pi^{-4}\sum_1^{\infty}n^{-4}{2n\choose n}^{-1}=2\pi^{-4}\int_0^{\pi/3}x\biggl(\log\bigl(2\sin(x/2)\bigr)\biggr)^2\,dx={17\over3240}$$ The part with the sum is an exercise on page 89 of Comtet, Advanced Combinatorics; the part with the integral was a remark of Lewin; there is some discussion in Alf van der Poorten's paper on Apéry's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$, "A proof that Euler missed."

Answer (score 15):

Let $v(n)$ be the supremum, over all symplectic embeddings of the disjoint 
union of $n$ equal balls into $B(1)$, of the fraction of the volume of $B(1)$ 
that is filled.   As of 1997, these $v(n)$ are known for all $n$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & n \geq 9
\\ \hline
v(n) & 1 & \frac12 & \frac34 & 1 & \frac45 & \frac{24}{25} &
  \frac{63}{64} & \frac{288}{289} & 1
\end{array}
$$
At least the cases $n=7$ and $n=8$ should be legitimate examples
given that $v(n)=1$ for all larger $n$ (and that it is not
obvious *a priori* that $v(n)$ is rational for any $n > 1$).
The cases $n\leq 9$ are due to McDuff and Polterovich (1994);
$n \geq 9$, to Biran (1997).  This is according to M.Hutchings,
[Recent 
progress on symplectic embedding problems in four dimensions](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/20/8093.long),
*PNAS* **108** #20 (2011), 8093-8099.  See OEIS sequences 
A125846 and A125847, where it is reported that 
"Explicit constructions for $n = 8$ and $n = 9$ are still unknown."

Answer (score 15):

For a prime number $p$, the number of nonisomorphic groups of order $p^n$ is $p^{(2/27)n^3 + O(n^{8/3})}$. I was surprised when I first saw this formula with leading coefficient $2/27$ in the exponent.

Answer (score 14):

There is a  nice "Birthday" probability value (not sure though if it fulfills the OP's criteria fully).

Suppose you have to get in line for a movie. The theatre announces that the first person who has a birthday matching any of the people in front of her or him will get a free ticket. Assuming uniform distribution of birthdays across the year, the aim is to find at which position you should get in line to maximize the probability of your win.

Some calculation shows that you should try to be the 20th person, and that
\begin{equation*}
  \text{Pr}(20) = \frac{249547857325289514001589444555797521991729152}
    {7721192983187403134097091636121110137939453125}
\end{equation*}

Comment: This answer fails on the "surprising" part; the large values are merely calculations. but the original puzzle is nice, so I included it here.

Comment: How does this problem treat leap years? And properly, shouldn't this be different based on whether the person was born on Feb. 29 or not?

Comment: @Random832 Assuming uniform distribution of birthdays across the year, it shouldn't matter whether the person was born on Feb 29, because just as many people were born on Feb 29 as on any other day of the year, right? If the probability of a birthday of Feb 29 is only about 1/4th of that of a birthday of Feb 28, then the distribution is not uniform across the year, merely uniform across every 4 (or 400 to be precise) years. Your comment does indicate that a uniform distribution of birthdays across the year is unrealistic. It's unrealistic even if you don't take leap years into account. :)

Comment: @hvd What? There must be only 1/4 as many people on Feb 29, as any other day... Say that the evening is a special event, where people born 1986-1990 gain entrance. Assuming same number of people from each year, there must be fewer with leap year birthday....

Comment: @PerAlexandersson "Assuming uniform distribution of birthdays across the year" (exact quote from this answer), no, I don't think that's right. Uniform distribution of birthdays across the year means that given a large enough sample size, for each day of the year (including Feb 29), the number of people with that day as their birthday is the same. What you're thinking of is when for each day, the number of people with that day as their birthday is the same. It's a subtle difference and your interpretation is less unrealistic, I'll admit that, but I don't think it matches this answer.

Comment: @hvd: You are of course right, I misinterpreted your comment somehow.

Comment: *The* year? Which year? This year, 2015, has 365 days for the cinema-goers to be uniformly distributed over. Next year, 2016, has 366 days for them. I don't know whether this answer assumed a 365 or a 366 day year, but either way I expect you'll get some big numbers as numerator and denominator. What would be surprising is if one of them simplified nicely, thereby disqualifying itself from being an answer to this question!

Comment: Related: [**MO 103892: Solving a modified birthday problem at a glance**](http://mathoverflow.net/q/103892).

Comment: @BenjaminDickman thanks for pointing out that link!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a particularly 'nice' number or question. The number 365 is arbitrary, and presumably any combinatorial question like these gives as result which is a fraction with very large numerator and denominator.

Comment: @jwg I agree with the not "nice" part; please see my 1st comment above. At the same time, observe that "nice" is about as subjective as it gets, and 365 is as "random / arbitrary" as any other number :-)

Comment: Jessop: Presumably the chance of a leap year is 1/4.

Answer (score 12):

Some answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32967/have-any-long-suspected-irrational-numbers-turned-out-to-be-rational) might provide examples for this question also:

For example, $32/27$, in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/39961/1056), about a bound on real zeros of chromatic polynomials for graphs.

Answer (score 12):

Not a huge denominator, but I still think it's amazing that $$\prod_{\text{$p$ prime}} \frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1} = \frac25.$$

Comment: True, but noted already in a previous answer by **Geoff Robinson** (in the equivalent $5/2$ form) that he then deleted because indeed the fraction is so simple.  To repeat my comment on that question:

Comment: Thus $2/5$ is the probability that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(c,d)$ for "random" $a,b,c,d$. math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/sol1.html But $2/5$ is surely not "special" enough for the OP. Maybe the probability that $\gcd(a,b,c,d,e,f)=\gcd(i,j,k,l,m,n)$?

Comment: (which is $\zeta(12)/\zeta(6)^2 = 691/715$)

Comment: Ok, but then we are back at the discussion of Bernoulli numbers...

Comment: The question has been designated as community wiki, which (in my opinion) means my opinion as OP should be irrelevant. For what it's worth, these are both cute examples, and yes, $691/715$ is a lovely fraction.

Comment: Noam, thanks for your comment and link, interesting! I'll leave my answer here so you won't have to post your comment again ;) Is it conceivable that if $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are i. i. d. positive integers, then regardless of their (common) distribution, $Pr(gcd(a,b) = gcd(c,d)) > 2/5$?

Comment: Hm, that last idea of mine was just silly, of course not...

Answer (score 12):

Randomly choose a subset $\{a,b,c,d\}$ of size exactly 4 uniformly from among all $N \choose 4$ size 4 subsets of $\{1,2,3,...,N\}$.

Form the polynomial $p(z) = 1 + z^a + z^b + z^c + z^d$.

What's the probability that $p(z)$ has at least one root on the unit circle? The probability depends on $N$, but how does the probability behave when $N$ approaches infinity?

Some plausible conjectures imply that the answer is $909/9464$. See paper A6 here: http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/vol12.html

Comment: In the paper (by Idris Mercer) linked, it is seen that if the size of 4 is substituted with a size of 3 or 2, this solution becomes "simpler" rational numbers, $\frac37$ respectively $\frac14$.

Answer (score 11):

For any sufficiently large even value of $n$, the Bernoulli number $B_n$ is probably a good example.

Comment: Steven, what is $n$? The answer has to be a particular rational number, not a sequence.

Comment: He probably had $B_{12}$ in mind.  The numerators of $B_n$ for $n \leq 14$ are all $0$ or $\pm 1$ except for $n=12$ when it's $691$ (and $B_{12}$ itself is $-691/2730$).  Hence the appearance of $691$ in Ramanujan's congruence for $\tau(n)$, "etc.".

Comment: @DanRomik:  For any sufficiently large even value of $n$, the Bernoulli number $B_n$ is a particular rational number, not a sequence.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies:  $B_{12}$ is a fine example, but $12$ probably doesn't count as sufficiently large, because $B_{14}=7/6$ seems insufficiently exotic.  But $n=16$ might work.

Comment: $$\pi^{-12}\sum_1^{\infty}n^{-12}={691\over638512875}$$

Comment: Steven, I agree that for any $n$, $B_n$ is a specific number. However, it is not true that for any sufficiently large $n$ the question "what is the $n$th Bernoulli number?" (or one of its equivalent forms) is a natural question. On the other hand, for $n=12$ it is actually pretty natural (for the reasons explained by Noam Elkies and Gerry Myerson), so $B_{12}$ is a good answer.

Comment: It's also a good vitamin.

Comment: @DanRomik:  My assertion (with which you are free to disagree) was that for sufficiently large even $n$, $B_n$ is probably the answer to some natural question.  I agree that "What is $n$th Bernoulli number?" does not count as a natural question.  That does not disprove the assertion.

Comment: I neither agree nor disagree, but I guess I don't see why you hold this belief. I'd be happy to be convinced that your assertion is correct.

Comment: @GerryMyerson a good vitamin and the only vitamin that contains a metal atom (indeed possibly the only metal-to-carbon bond in normal biochemistry, right?).

Comment: Are there any bad vitamins?

Comment: Well there's the poison formerly known as Vitamin B$_{17}$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amygdalin

Comment: @Noam, "Vitamin B_12 is the preeminent bioorganometallic species," according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioorganometallic_chemistry but some other biochemical metal-to-carbon bonds do get a look in on that page. Perhpas you could post a question to biology.stackexchange.com ....

Comment: Thanks.  Meanwhile, other examples of "bad vitamin" are overdoses of some good vitamins.  But yes, this is not "math" but "overflow" and belongs in a different forum...

Answer (score 11):

[$5\over 8$ths of (propositional) classical tautologies are intuitionistically valid](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007211001333).

This is surprising to me on multiple levels. First, it's fairly robust: a couple different reasonable approaches yield the same answer. Second, of course the fact that it's rational strikes me as deeply weird, I'd have definitely expected something quite odd. Finally, I'm quite surprised that it's greater than $1\over 2$ - my naive take would definitely be that a randomly-picked classical tautology probably isn't intuitionistically valid.

Comment: This is very cool! I would not have expected one to be able to even compute such numbers for formal systems and it now begs related questions for example “what % of statements are independent of a system”

Answer (score 8):

If $f(\pi)$ is a length of the longest increasing subsequence of a permutation $\pi$, than $f(\pi)$ concentrates when $\pi$ runs over $S_n$, and expected (or median, or whatever) value behaves like $c\sqrt{n}$. There are no obvious reasons why $c$ must be good number, but it appears to be equal to 2. This was known as Ulam's problem, solved by Vershik and Kerov and by Logan and Shepp. Of course, 2 is not very original rational number, but I believe that this example is something that Dan is asking about.

And let me popularize here an intriguing [problem](http://www.renyi.hu/~barany/cikkek/loncon_final.pdf) by Ambrus and Bárány: if we consider $n$ random independent points in a triangle $ABC$ and look for a convex chain $AP_1\dots P_kB$, $P_i$ are chosen from our points and $k$ has to be maximized, then $k$ is concentrated near $c\sqrt[3]{n}$ (not a surprise), and numerical computations suggest that $c=3$. My opinion is that it would be great if this is true and we really have $2\sqrt{n}$ for the longest monotone chain and $3\sqrt[3]{n}$ for the longest convex chain.

Answer (score 8):

**John H. Conway's prime producing machine** (also known as **PRIMEGAME**) is a weird algorithm that produces prime numbers using the following bizarre ordered sequence of fourteen rational numbers:
$$
\frac{17}{91},\ \ 
\frac{78}{85},\ \ 
\frac{19}{51},\ \ 
\frac{23}{38},\ \ 
\frac{29}{33},\ \ 
\frac{77}{29},\ \ 
\frac{95}{23},\ \ 
\frac{77}{19},\ \ 
\frac{1}{17},\ \ 
\frac{11}{13},\ \ 
\frac{13}{11},\ \ 
\frac{15}{2},\ \ 
\frac{1}{7},\ \ 55.
$$
See [here](https://oeis.org/wiki/Conway's_PRIMEGAME), [here](http://oeis.org/A202138) and (subscription required) [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690263?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Answer (score 7):

The maximum density of a letter in an infinite
ternary squarefree word in $255/653$. See P. Ochem, Letter frequency in infinite
repetition-free words, *Theoretical Computer                                     Science* **380** (2007), 388--392. The minimum density of a letter in an infinite
ternary squarefree word is $883/3215$. See A. Khalyavin, The minimal density of a letter in an infinite ternary square-free word is 883/3215, *J. Integer                        Sequences* **10**(2) (2007), Article 07.6.5.

Answer (score 7):

It is [well-known](https://mathoverflow.net/q/2014/494920) that if a stick is broken at two random points, the probability that the pieces can form a triangle is $\frac14$.

If a stick is broken at *five* random points, the probability that the pieces can form *two* triangles [turns out to be](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4859204/398708)

$$\frac{21025}{76076}.$$

Answer (score 6):

The game of Bidding Chess (see [Discrete Bidding Games](http://users.math.yale.edu/~sp547/pdf/Discrete-bidding-games.pdf) by Mike Develin and Sam Payne) offers some rather tricky rational values.

Let's put the two kings on their original squares e1 and e8, and a white knight on g1 (admittedly not a natural position for any mathematical reason). As is explained in the paper, bidding games are related to random turn games, where before each move, a coin toss decides who gets to move. The objective of the game is to capture the opponent's king, so there are no concepts of check, checkmate or stalemate.

We can define two numbers $\alpha \leq \beta$ (representing the value of the position from White's perspective) such that $\alpha$ is White's maximum probability of winning, and $\beta$ is White's maximum probability of not losing, taken over all White's strategies (and minimizing over all Black's strategies). For Black, the maximum probability of winning is $1-\beta$ and the maximum probability of not losing is $1-\alpha$.

It is not true in general that $\alpha=\beta$, but in this particular position, numerical evidence (!) suggests that $\alpha = \beta$, and that they are equal to
$$
{\tiny 140297187507809718787571560535429924880742491099805023919271172220178831973930689386662219848285322420407060840990534312850343}\\
\big /\\
{\tiny 194465010677647568859234587998029627946213150285790861705846175978932032134223961344086399663594245257797038922571722208051200}$$

Comment: This is under some assumption on how many chips each player has at the outset?

Comment: Gerry, just assuming one can bid any real number. Or equivalently, taking the "infinitely many chips"-limit. So the given number is the limit proportion of chips that Black needs in order to win/survive.

Comment: I feel like the huge number here isn't _too_ surprising - presumably this is related to some particular Markov chains on the $(64\times63\times62)$-node position graph...

Answer (score 6):

Many delicate estimates in analytic number theory lead to bounds involving unusual rational numbers. Two examples I am aware of are:

1. The **Lindelof hypothesis** asks about the rate of growth of $|\zeta(1/2+it)|$ as $|t|\to\infty$, that is the infimum $\lambda$ of all numbers $c>0$ such that $|\zeta(1/2+it)|=O(|t|^c)$. The conjecture is that $\lambda=0$. This is known to follow from the Riemann hypothesis but does not imply it. A series of papers by many authors over the last 100+ years, starting with Lindelof in 1908, proved that $\lambda$ is bounded by
   $$
   \frac14, \frac16, \frac{163}{988}, \frac{27}{164}, \frac{229}{1392}, \frac{19}{116}, \frac{15}{92}, \frac{6}{37}, \frac{173}{1067}, \frac{35}{216}, \frac{139}{858}, \frac{32}{205}, \frac{53}{342}
   $$
   (it's not obvious at a glance, but this is a decreasing sequence!). The last and currently best known bound of $\frac{53}{342}\approx 0.1549$ is due to [Bourgain (2014)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5794). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_hypothesis) for more details.
2. There is a similar story about the **Dirichlet divisor problem**, which is the problem of estimating the average order of the number of divisors $\sigma(n)$. That is, denote
   $$
   \sigma(n) = \sum_{d|n} 1, \qquad D(x) = \sum_{n\le x} d(n).
   $$
   Dirichlet proved that
   $$ D(x) = x \log x + x(2\gamma-1) + \Delta(x)
   $$
   where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\Delta(x) = O(x^{1/2})$. The Dirichlet divisor problem asks for the infimum $\theta$ of numbers $c$ such that $\Delta(x)=O(x^c)$. In this case a lower bound due to Hardy says that $\theta\ge\frac14$. As with the Lindelof hypothesis, Dirichlet's upper bound $\theta\le \frac12$ has been improved over the years by many people who published the successive bounds
   $$
   \frac12, \frac13, \frac{33}{100}, \frac{27}{82}, \frac{15}{46}, \frac{12}{37}, \frac{346}{1067}, \frac{35}{108}, \frac{7}{22}, \frac{131}{416}.
   $$
   The most recent bound $\frac{131}{416}\approx 0.3149$ is due to [Huxley (2003)](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/87/3/591). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function). (Paraphrasing a joke Cris Moore made recently on the Domino Forum, it would be nice to look up this sequence on OEIS and see what it converges to...)

Of course all these numbers are only non-sharp bounds, so they are sociological rather than mathematical constants and therefore a bit lame as an answer to the question. I still think the fact that such numbers appear repeatedly in analytic number theory says something interesting (and potentially deep) about the known methods we have for estimating number theoretic analytic functions. I'm not an expert on this, but would be happy to hear from someone who can add insight on this phenomenon.

Comment: I, too, am no expert on these matters, but I wonder whether we are dealing with results relying on "exponent pairs". E.g., we find in Sid Graham's paper, An algorithm for computing optimal exponent pairs, http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-33/2/203.full.pdf  that the infimum of $k+\ell$ over all exponent pairs $(k,\ell)$ is at least $73604982/88785387$.

Answer (score 6):

The best current lower bound on the [packing density of regular tetrahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron_packing) is $4000/4671$, which is the density of an explicit periodic packing by Chen, Engel, and Glotzer.

Answer (score 6):

This example comes from the humble cubic curve.

The diagram shows any cubic curve with turning points, and a tangent line at a turning point.

In the enclosed region, inscribe a triangle in the natural way. (The base of the triangle is coincident with the tangent line, the top vertex of the triangle is at the other turning point, the left vertex is at the intersection of the tangent line and the curve, and the upper right side of the triangle is tangent to the curve.)

[image]

The ratio of the area of the triangle, to the area of the region in which it is inscribed, is always

$$\frac{200}{243}$$

If we rotate each shape completely around the tangent line, then the ratio of the volumes of rotation is always

$$\frac{14000}{19683}$$

**Proof**

Transform the cubic, by translating and stretching (which preserve the ratio of areas), to $y=x^2(x+1)$, which has a local maximum point $\left(-\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{27}\right)$. To find the $x$-intercept of the upper right side of the triangle, find the equation of the tangent to the curve at $x=a$ and make it pass through the local maximum point. This gives $a=-\frac16$, so the $x$-intercept of the upper right side of the triangle is at $x=-\frac{2}{27}$. So the ratio of areas is $\frac{\frac12\left(\frac{4}{27}\right)\left(-\frac{2}{27}+1\right)}{\int_{-1}^0(x^2(x+1))\mathrm dx}=\frac{200}{243}$.

The ratio of volumes follows easily.

**Related results**

The diagram shows any cubic curve, with a tangent line, and a another tangent line at the point where the first tangent line meets the curve.

[image]

The ratio of the areas of the enclosed regions is always $1:16$ ([reference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicCurve.html)). (This doesn't answer the OP since $1:16$ is not very "special".)

And of course there is Archimedes' [quadrature of the parabola](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/JAC/NYB/exhaustion2.pdf).

**Higher degree polynomials?**

I don't think higher degree polynomials yield these kinds of results. In the proof above with the cubic, the first step was to transform the curve to $y=x^2(x+1)$. But if we try that with a higher degree polynomial, there would be more roots (in addition to $x=0$ and $x=-1$), so we can't say anything in general about the area or volume.

Comment: Interesting! Perhaps it's also worthwhile to look at such areas of inscribed regions of higher-order polynomials

Comment: Can you give a reference for the result?

Comment: @DanRomik I don't have a reference, but I've added a proof.

Comment: @MaxMuller I've added a remark about higher-order polynomials.

Answer (score 5):

In the dissection of the unit square into the least number of square pieces of different sizes ([Duijvestijn's dissection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square#Simple_squared_squares)), the area of the largest piece is $\frac{625}{3136}$ and the harmonic mean of all areas is $\frac{27812926939574093625}{7042788441228875157149}$.

Comment: This is very nice, but may I ask why the harmonic mean is interesting to compute (as opposed to the arithmetic mean, or any other function of the areas)?

Comment: Just because it has a simple name and gives a scarier rational :)

Comment: Even using area instead of side is artificially inflating the relevant size: area 625/3136 is just side 25/56.

Comment: I feel that an area is a natural measure of size in this case, because areas must add up to $1$.

Answer (score 5):

This may not exactly qualify, because it's still only the *conjectured* answer to a question.

**The question:** Consider all $2$-colorings of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.  What is the minimum number of monochromatic $3$-term arithmetic progressions (solutions to $x+z=2y$ where all of $x,y,z$ are the same color) formed, and what coloring achieves it?

**The conjectured answer** (supported by a fair amount of computational evidence): The minimum is asymptotic to $\frac{117}{2192} n^4$.  The optimal coloring is to divide your interval into alternating blocks of size proportional to
$$\frac{28}{548}, \frac{6}{548}, \frac{28}{548}, \frac{37}{548}, \frac{59}{548}, \frac{116}{548}, \frac{116}{548}, \frac{59}{548}, \frac{37}{548}, \frac{28}{548}, \frac{6}{548}, \frac{28}{548}.$$

The best lower bound currently known is $\frac{1675}{32768}(1+o(1)) n^4$, achieved by [Parrilo, Robertson, and Saracino](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609532.pdf) using semidefinite programming (this paper also contains the conjecture described here).

Comment: This is fascinating - is there any sense for where that factor of 137 in the denominator comes from?

Comment: I don't really have a sense if it has any meaning other than coincidence.  The problem ends up being equivalent to minimizing $x^T A x$, where $x$ is a $\pm 1$ vector, and $a_{ij}$ is the number of progressions containing both $i$ and $j$.  The conjectured answer comes from assuming (after running some experiments) a $12$ block solution with roughly these block sizes, and writing down the local optimality condition that perturbing the block sizes can't reduce the number of solutions.  The original function was quadratic, so this turns into a system of linear equations in the block sizes.

Comment: (c'td) You can see the system on page 7 here http://www.math.ucr.edu/~costello/research/constellations.pdf .  The coefficients of the system are all small integers, and the $137$ just shows up along the way when you solve it.

Comment: Surely the $137$ comes from the fine-structure constant, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Numerological_explanations_and_multiverse_theory

Comment: Replace n^4 with n^2 everywhere

Answer (score 4):

In the recent paper [The density of primes dividing a particular non-linear recurrence sequence](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02464) by Gorman et al, it is proved that the density of the primes dividing a certain sequence $(b_n)$ is $\frac{179}{336}$, where $(b_n)$ is defined by $b_0=1$, $b_1=2$, $b_2=1$, $b_3=-3$, and the recurrence
$$
b_n = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{b_{n-1}b_{n-3}-b_{n-2}^2}{b_{n-4}} & \textrm{if }n \not\equiv 2 \ \ (\textrm{mod }3),\\
\displaystyle\frac{b_{n-1}b_{n-3}-3b_{n-2}^2}{b_{n-4}} & \textrm{if }n \equiv 2 \ \ 
(\textrm{mod }3).\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: That's a good example but it's basically the same as the "Somos sequence" example in the original question (the $b_n$ form a "Somos-4" sequence).

Comment: Thanks, I love these sorts of results. I edited your answer to add more detail. Note that this example is a bit similar to example 2 in my question (and there is a nonempty intersection between the authors of both papers). I'm curious if there are many other density results along these lines.

Comment: Very similar, yes . . .   It must be known that every (weighted) Somos sequence related with a theta function has this kind of behavior (including all "Somos-$k$" for $k=4,5,6,7$).

Answer (score 4):

[Elevated from a comment to an answer at suggestion of OP]

In my paper, Rational products of sines of rational angles, Aeq. Math. 45 (1993) 70-82, I found all the solutions of
$$\sin\pi x\sin\pi y\sin\pi z\sin\pi w=r$$
in rational $x,y,z,w,r$. These included
$$\sin\pi/42\sin5\pi/14\sin8\pi/21\sin10\pi/21=1/16$$
and
$$\sin\pi/39\sin9\pi/26\sin14\pi/39\sin11\pi/26=1/16$$

Answer (score 3):

I can hardly ever be more surprised than with this expression (by Ramanujan):

$$
\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{9801} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ (4k)! (1103+26390k) }{ (k!)^4 396^{4k} } = \frac1{\pi}.
$$

In particular, it's intriguing that such "special" rational numbers (in the sense defined by the OP) appear in a series related to good old $\pi$.

Comment: That isn't rational.

Comment: @PyRulez, the LHS has some cool fractions, which are rational except for the $\sqrt{2}$ factor. Regardless, it is never really wrong to cite Ramanujan...

Comment: To me, the "rules of the game" of the actual question are not so clear if PyRulez's objection is dismissed.

Comment: @ToddTrimble You could rephrase it as: $$
\frac{4}{9801} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ (4k)! (1103+26390k) }{ (k!)^4 396^{4k} } = \frac{\sqrt 2}{\pi}.
$$
and then the fact that those "special" rational numbers appear on the LHS is still surprising (what do they have to do with $\sqrt 2/\pi$?)

Comment: @ToddTrimble I admit that such formulas are not exactly what I intended when I posted the question. I was primarily thinking of results where the answer would include a single rational number. However, it is now CW, and the community has interpreted my question a bit differently. There are several other answers (including my own!) that ignore this rule of the game and were still highly upvoted. Nonetheless, they are all beautiful and interesting so I'm okay with it; let's not spoil the fun with too much pedantry.

Comment: @LuisMendo I can't see how this is responsive to my comment. Is the question now allowing not just single rational values, but *sequences* of rational values that converge to... whatever? Couldn't you then just stick a pin in Ramanujan's notebooks and wherever you land, there you have it?

Comment: @ToddTrimble I partly agree with you. But to me, this answer fulfills the requirement _a "special" rational number makes a surprising appearance as an answer to a natural question_.

Comment: Luis, which special number? :-) @DanRomik , I have to reject the charge of pedantry here; for the sake of the Community I think it's a good idea to get clear on what you're accepting. Please make another edit to your question, if need be. I don't see your answer as an example by the way, since you are really giving a *sequence of equalities* each of which is in some sense surprising, not a series with rational terms which add to something irrational.

Comment: Sorry for another comment. I guess if the identity were rephrased as $$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ (4k)! (1103+26390k) }{ (k!)^4 396^{4k} } = \frac{9801}{4},$$ then it would look closer to one of Dan's answers (that I didn't object to), although the $\frac{9801}{4}$ looks less "exotic" when written as $(\frac{99}{2})^2$. :-)

Comment: @ToddTrimble, good points, but I'm very happy with the answers we've been getting, even those that don't technically meet my guidelines (e.g., Richard Stanley's), so I don't see a need to edit the question.

Comment: @DanRomik Okay, fair enough. I do note however that Richard Stanley demurred posting his response as an answer, for reasons that I think are related to the point I was trying to make. :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Interesting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297901/a-conjectured-mathematical-constant-for-base-10-normal-numbers) rational constant concerning base-10 normal numbers.

> Let $a$ be a real number with a base-10 decimal representation $a_1a_2\ldots a_n \ldots$ Denote the number of ways to write $a_n$ as the sum of positive integers as $p(a_n)$ - also called the partition of $a_n$. I write $A(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n p(a_k)$ and $B(n)= \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ and set $$\beta(a)=\lim_{n\to \infty}{A(n)\above 1.5 pt B(n)}$$ If $a$ is a base-10 normal number then  $\beta(a)={97 \above 1.5 pt 45}$ .

Note the converse of the above statement is false!

Numerically ${97\above 1.5pt 45}$ can be written $2.15\ldots$.  If we believe $\pi$ is normal then we would expect $\beta(\pi)={97 \above 1.5 pt 45}$. Up to the $500\text{ }000$-th digit $\beta(\pi)=2.153781\ldots$ See the plot of $\beta(\pi)$ below. Note the blue line is the constant value ${97\above 1.5 pt 45}$ and the orange "graph" are the values of $\beta(\pi)$.

[image]

Comment: As written the sum is infinite.  If you fix it (to what's written in the stack exchange post) I would argue that this is unsurprising.  You could replace $p$ with any rational-valued function and it would still be true with constant $(p(0) + p(1) + \cdots + p(9))/(0 + 1 + \cdots + 9)$.

Comment: @TimCarson I finally understand what you mean by "any rational-valued function. " I understand now.

Comment: Actually now I don't remember why I said rational-valued.  It seems like any function $p : \{0, 1, ..., 9\} \to \mathbb{R}$ would do.