# Simple recurrence that fails to be integer for the first time at the 44th term

Tags: nt.number-theory, recurrences

The sequence defined by $a_0=a_1 =1$ and 
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i^2, \quad n > 1
$$
fails to be integer for the first time at $a_{44}$. Why??

You can verify the statement by computing the sequence mod 43 (see more commentary [here (day 5, problem 3)](http://turnbull.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/Zagier/Problems.html)). That's not a very satisfying answer though. Is there a good reason for this behavior?

Comment: See also, this MO answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/217894/25028 with a link to the OEIS: http://oeis.org/A003504

Comment: Some information can be found in H. Ibstedt, _Some sequences of large integers,_ Fibonacci Quart. 28 (1990), 200-203. ([Link](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/28-3/ibstedt.pdf))

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Copying my explanation from https://mathoverflow.net/a/217894/25028

The recurrence formula can be rewritten as
$$a_2=2,\qquad a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n\cdot (a_n+n-1)}n,\quad n\geq 2,$$
which somewhat justifies why $a_n$ remains integer for quite a while. It shows that $a_n$ accumulates most of the factors of the previous terms and gains some new ones. The division by $n$ happens to hit the existing factors up until $n=43$.

Another example of this kind is given by
$$b_2=2,\qquad b_{n+1}=\frac{b_n\cdot (b_n+n+5)}n,\quad n\geq 2,$$
which remains integer for up to $n=59$.

**ADDED.** [OEIS A292996](https://oeis.org/A292996) gives indices of first noninteger terms in similar sequences.

Some spin-off questions:

- [Is there any positive integer sequence $c_{n+1}=\frac{c_n(c_n+n+d)}n$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/282159/7076)
- [Can these sequences stay integer-valued as many times as we want and then fail?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/282174/7076)

Comment: Is there any positive sequence of this type ($c_{n+1}=c_n(c_n+n+\alpha)/n$ with integer $\alpha$ which remains integer forever?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: Good question! I don't have an immediate answer. It may be worth to ask it at MO separately.

Comment: OK, let me do it.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: the recursion only holds for $n\geq2$, right?

Comment: @SamHopkins: Sure.

Comment: Do you know of any record beyond n=59 (for strictly incerasing sequences)?

Comment: The formula you gave is wrong (the formula you put down just repeats (1,1,1,1...))

Comment: @JorgePerez: It works for $n\geq 2$ as explained in the comments above. I'll make it clear in the answer.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin: There are many such examples with growing records. E.g., $c_2=2$ and $c_{n+1}=c_n(c_n+n+16)/n$ give integers when $n<73$.