# Is there any positive integer sequence $c_{n+1}=\frac{c_n(c_n+n+d)}n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, integer-sequences, recurrences

In a [recent answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/282154/17581) Max Alekseyev provided two recurrences of the form mentioned in the title which stay integer for a long time. However, they eventually fail.

> **QUESTION** Is there any (**added:** strictly increasing) sequence of positive integers $c_1,c_2,c_3,\dots$ satisfying the relation 
>   $$
>   c_{n+1}=\frac{c_n(c_n+n+d)}n
> $$
>   for for all $n\geq 1$ (and some integer constant $d$)?

(As Sam Hopkins notes, it would be also very interesting if the indices of the sequence start from some $k>1$ rather than from 1.)

Comment: We can express this as a time-invariant dynamical system by adding an additional variable $n$, i.e. $(x,y) \to (x+1, y(y+x+d)/x)$.  For each prime $p$, this naturally gives an algebraic dynamical system on $\mathbb Q_p \times \mathbb Z_p$. One wants to know if there is a $d$ such that all these systems stay inside $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$ forever.  Maybe techniques of $p$-adic algebraic dynamics would be helpful here?

Comment: A note that you may want to allow the sequence to start at $c_k$ for some $k>1$ because otherwise the motivating example is not really of this form.

Comment: If we ignore the division by n, a necessary condition for the integrality of the original sequence is for the modified $c_{p+1}$ to divide $p$ for all primes $p$. Might it be possible to show that given any $c_1$ and $d$, that there must exist a prime $p$ such that this is not the case?

Comment: @WillSawin: phrased this way, the transformation sort of looks like those found in the theory of cluster algebras, so maybe if there is a positive answer to the question it could be found via the "Laurent phenomenon."